# How to pause autoplay in react swiper on hover?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how can i pause autoplay on swiper when i hover but i cannot find it anywhere

```
<Swiper
                    spaceBetween={0}
                    navigation={{
                        prevEl: navigationPrevRef.current,
                        nextEl: navigationNextRef.current,
                    }}
                    autoplay={{
                        delay: 3000,
                        pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
                    }}
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a work around hope it helps those who are still facing this issue.
Just give a ref to your swpier use onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave on your parent div

```
import {useRef} from "react";

    const swiperRefLocal = useRef()

    const handleMouseEnter = () => {
        swiperRefLocal?.current?.swiper?.autoplay?.stop()
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        swiperRefLocal?.current?.swiper?.autoplay?.start()
    };

<div onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}>
   <Swiper
                    spaceBetween={0}
                    ref={swiperRefLocal}
                    navigation={{
                        prevEl: navigationPrevRef.current,
                        nextEl: navigationNextRef.current,
                    }}
                    autoplay={{
                        delay: 3000,
                    }}
>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

In this case, all you should need is the `pauseOnMouseEnter` attribute set to `true`, like you have. The issue seems to be because you don't have the autoplay module connected.

You should have imported these:

```
import { Autoplay, Navigation } from 'swiper'
import 'swiper/css'
import 'swiper/css/navigation'
```

Now that `Autoplay` has been imported, we need connect it to the individual Swiper:

```
<Swiper
  // spaceBetween can be removed if you have it set to 0
  // spaceBetween={0}
  navigation={{
    prevEl: navigationPrevRef.current,
    nextEl: navigationNextRef.current,
  }}
  autoplay={{
    disableOnInteraction: false, // Optional, but recommended
    delay: 3000
    pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
  }}
  modules={[ Autoplay, Navigation ]}
>
```

I hope that helps. Swiper can be a headache. Their documentation is very in depth.